# Xamarin: use NDK-built .so

Tags: build, android-ndk, java-native-interface, xamarin

I made two simple functions (set and return an int) on eclipse (Android project) in C. I used ndk-build to produce a .so. How can i use this .so on Xamarin and consume those two functions on my Xamarin.Android project?

Thanks!

Comment: The link to "ndk-build" is broken...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let’s assume we have a shared library called MyTest.so and we want to use it in the Xamarin.Android project. The MyTest.so consists of a function

```
int MyTest_GetValue();
```

Now, we need to use this function on Xamarin.Android project. Here are the steps so as to succeed:

Step 1: Create a new folder inside the Xamarin.Android project called lib and sub-folder armeabi. Copied my .so library to be used inside the armeabi folder as stated [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries)

Step 2: Set the properties of the library.so (imported library) Build action  to "AndroidNativeLibrary" and Copy to output to "Always Copy".

Step 3: (Working in Xamarin.Android Class eg: MainActivity.cs)

- Include the namespace InteropServices by “using System.Runtime.InteropServices;”
- Use the standard DllImport in the project to import the native library as below:

  ```
  [DllImport("MyTest.so")] 
  public extern static int MyTest_GetValue();// with exact Functtion Name, Type & Params in the .so Lib.
  ```

Step 4: Consume the function above (`MyTest_GetValue()`) in the application.

For Example:

```
int value= MyTest_GetValue();

Console.Writeline(value.ToString());
```

**Mission Accomplished!** :D

Comment: Can you show an example function with an [out] argument? Like
 bool MyTest_GetValue(string* retVal);  

Thanks

Comment: As far as i can think of, it should not be any different using [out] arguments. Performing steps 1 &2, then step 3 that includes function with [out] arguments and finally step 4 for consuming that function should work fine. 
Note: Xamarin has changed a lot since 2013 (this question).