# Include java *.so library in Xamarin Android project

Tags: android, xamarin, shared-libraries, .so

I'm trying to use a *.so library inside a Xamarin Android project, just as used in Java project.
I tried putting the library in the path: lib/armeabi/library.so and in the properties of the file:

- Build action: AndroidNativeLibrary
- Copy to output: Always

Also, i tried the following code to import a method, as described in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15902529/5610132

Code:

```
[DllImport("libVPOS3515.so")] 
public extern static int Lib_McrRead(byte keyNo, byte mode, byte []track1, byte []track2, byte []track3);
```

But, how can I use the classes included in the library?

Answer (score 0):

**If your DllImport is:**

> public extern static int Lib_McrRead(byte keyNo, byte mode, byte[] track1, byte[] track2, byte[] track3);

**Something like this:**

```
byte keyNo = {?};
byte mode = {?};
byte[] track1 = {?};
byte[] track2 = {?};
byte[] track3 = {?};
int retValue = Lib_McrRead(keyNo, mode, track1, track2, track3);
```

*(I do not know what what the parameter's value should be of course...)*

Comment: The issue is that I want to use the classes included in the library, not just the methods.

Comment: Not sure you understand what p/invoke interop is, try reading about class marshalling maybe it will help : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#class-and-structure-marshaling

Comment: Also you you are trying to bind c++ classes to use within managed code, then look at CXXI, this transformed to CppSharp. http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html and https://github.com/mono/CppSharp

Comment: I have the classes from the so implemented in a Java project (but i need to use them in Xamarin), they're used as imports, but I'm not sure what language it is. I thought it was java because of the imports.  Anyway, thank you for the links, I will continue researching.

Comment: Binding of Java Libraries would be done via Xamarin's `Managed Callable Wrappers` I would highly recommend going to the native language of the class and not trying to mix multiple levels of marshaling as that is a recipe for failure as debugging would be a nightmare if you could get it to even work correctly... ;-)  i.e. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/